VS Code setting for editor.lineHeightAfterBracket for empty lines specifically?
In VS Code (Version: 1.91.1), I want my code view to have editor.lineHeight = 1.5 for single lines and editor.lineHeight = 2.25 for back-to-back new lines. Is this possible?
I searched for extensions and was expecting something existed to solve my issue and struck out. Co-pilot also agreed that nothing like that exists as an extension.

Since you only want a special case for back to back newlines (basically for empty lines), I think you could theoretically get the same effect with an extension that changes the font size of such lines. For that, see How to change font size of specific parts of code in VS Code?. Whether there exists an extension that actually does this or not is something I don't know. You could try to make it. I'm not aware of any builtin setting that does this, and I doubt there ever will be one.
